Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReactCurrentOwner')
I just started making an web app using next.js with react and got this error message, here is the code in question:
'use client';
import * as THREE from "three";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { ContactShadows, Float, Environment } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Suspense, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import gsap from "gsap";
import { div } from "three/webgpu";
import Geometries from "three/src/renderers/common/Geometries.js";

export default function Shapes() {
    return (
        <div className="row-span-1 row-start-1 -mt-9 aspect-square md:col-span-1 md:col-start-2 md:mt-0">
            <Canvas className="z-0" shadows gl={{antialias:false}} dpr={[1, 1.5]} camera={{position: [0, 0, 25], fov:30, near:1, far:40}}>
                <Suspense fallback={null}>
                    <ContactShadows
                        position={[0, -3.5, 0]}
                        opacity={0.65}
                        scale={40}
                        blur={1}
                        far={9} 
                    />
                    <Environment preset="studio" />
                </Suspense>
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    );
}`

and here are my dependencies in my package.json file:
"dependencies": { "@prismicio/client": "^7.13.1", "@prismicio/next": "^1.7.1", "@prismicio/react": "^2.9.1", "@react-three/drei": "^9.120.4", "@react-three/fiber": "^8.17.10", "@types/three": "^0.170.0", "clsx": "^2.1.1", "gsap": "^3.12.5", "next": "^15.1.0", "react": "^18.2.0", "react-dom": "^18.2.0", "three": "^0.170.0" }
I believe the issue is mismatched dependencies, but I have no idea how to resolve this
I tried fixing the dependencies by reverting to older versions, but it did not seem to fix the issue.

Instead of giving the error you received in the title, give it in the place where you ask your question and write a short but concise title that describes your problem in the title section.
